# C# .Net FrameworkにてUserControlを縦積みにしたいのですが、なにを使用するのがよいのでしょうか？

Tags: c#, .net

以下画像のように`UserControl`を積み重ねたいのですが、親要素?には何を使えばいいでしょうか？
スクロールが可能なもので、軽量なものを探しています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 手元の環境では[FlowLayoutPanel](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel)を使用してAutoScrollプロパティをTrue、FlowDirectionプロパティをTopDown、WrapContentsプロパティをFalseに設定する方法でスクロール可能でした。この方法では問題がありますか？

Comment: この記事 [Using User Control inside Listbox or Listview on WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675876/using-user-control-inside-listbox-or-listview-on-winforms) のコメントでもWinFormsでは`FlowLayoutPanel`/`TableLayoutPanel`/`Panel`が良いだろうとあるようです。一方WPFではそれに対応するのは`WrapPanel`/`StackPanel`/`Grid`/`Canvas`のようです。[Windows フォーム コントロールおよび同等の WPF コントロール](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/windows-forms-controls-and-equivalent-wpf-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: FlowLayoutPanelで設定を教えてくださったものにして、UseControlを100個積み重ねて、一気に下にスクロールすると描画が遅いんですよね。ListViewの仮想化みたいのが使えればいいのですが

Comment: スクロール中の描画を抑制するしかないんじゃないですかね。画面上のコントロールが多いと、どうしても重くなるのは避けられないです。https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/control/beginupdate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WindowsFormsではコントロールごとにウィンドウハンドルが生成される関係で大量のコントロール配置をするUIデザインは解決策のない状況になります。

昔からコントロールが多いと重い、遅いという話題は尽きません。
http://bbs.wankuma.com/index.cgi?mode=al2&namber=9554&KLOG=22
https://dobon.net/vb/bbs/log3-19/11327.html
https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/bbs/phpBB/viewtopic.php?topic=15749&forum=7&start=16

このため、大量のコントロールを配置するような画面仕様を避けることを考えた方が良いでしょう。

たとえば、UserControlは10個くらいにして、スクロールしたら中身を入れ換えて表示して、擬似的にスクロールしているように見せるなど。
（実際には、1ページに10個表示、ページ切り換えボタンで11個目～、21個目～からと表示を切り替えるようなUIが良いかもしれません）

Answer (score 0):

コントロールが多くなると描画回数と裏で発生するウィンドウメッセージの送受信量が膨大になり、それだけで相当な負荷になるので、どうしても速度は低下します。
DataGridView、スプレッドシート系のコンポーネント（有償のが殆どですが…）、組み込みブラウザ等をカスタマイズして、それっぽい入力画面を作るのも手かもしれません。